# Should time I spent for researching, tracked?

Tags: work-time

For the last three weeks I have been working as a working student in the software development arena (and it's also the first time working in a business).

Well, I am new to the project and the billing is done via JIRA, where I track the time myself. However, I see myself searching for very simple solutions most of the time (Android Dev, which I am kinda new). But sometimes there are bugs I can't find a solution for.

Should I track the time I spent researching, too?
My contract says to work 20hrs per week at maximum (regulated by law in germany), and researching - which includes finding the correct classes to modify, reading docs and searching on SO for example - takes much much more time than writing actual code (and testing it).

Comment: What did your supervisor/boss say when you asked?  Surely they should define how your time is booked.

Comment: This is going to vary depending on company policy. You are best off asking your manager.

Comment: How to book your hours is company specific, so I'm voting to close this question as such. You will have to ask your boss.

Comment: @Erik is correct here.  The categorization for booking time is company specific.  Even though most companies might simply want to book the time that your ass is on the chair, others might want more granularity for project budget reasons and reporting.  The only person who can answer this question for you with any degree of accuracy is your boss or project manager.  Adding my VTC to help prevent ambiguous/misleading answers.

Comment: I imagine the universal consensus on software development is that figuring out what code to write where and how is very much billable time (within limits), so I'm not convinced this question is company-specific.

Answer (score 4):

Researching solutions to current work is part of the job.  Senior people need less time for this unless it's a complex issue, junior need more.  This is a known fact.  Your estimates on work as well as time to code is all inclusive of research, coding, debugging and sometimes unit testing is part of it too depending on how the company breaks it down.

Yes, include this as the total amount and be clear if asked that you are having to look alot of stuff up but are learning alot as well.  That is the goal of a new developer to continually learn and grow in ability while accomplishing tasks.  If they wanted someone to just spit out product they would hire a senior person, not a new one.  Cheaper with the understanding it takes longer due to having to learn as you go.

Jira work log is a generic bucket that decreases, but you can log work as what you actually did for each time you worked it.  Put the comment in there for the research and the code you did when you log it.  **However, it should be relevant to the specific task.**  If it's general info like how to code, I wouldn't consider that relevant.

Comment: _"Senior people need less time for this unless it's a complex issue, junior need more."_ - one of the main reasons seniors are paid more, apart from experience - they produce more in the same time.